# Submit redirects to Home page, DB Error: syntax error

Tags: civicontribute

I am using CiviCRM 4.7.8 on Joomla Joomla! 3.5.1 Stable [ Unicorn ].  When I go to my Donate (civicrm contribute page), the first time I submit the form, I am just redirected to the main front page.  No error message or confirmation page.  Subsequent form submissions, give me the following error and debug info.  This happens even when I submit a blank form.  How can I solve this issue?

DB Error: syntax error

Database Error Code: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)' at line 1, 1064
Additional Details:

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

```
[code] => -2
[message] => DB Error: syntax error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT 0 id1, 0 id2, 0 weight LIMIT 0 GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)' at line 1]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT 0 id1, 0 id2, 0 weight LIMIT 0 GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)' at line 1]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT 0 id1, 0 id2, 0 weight LIMIT 0 GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)' at line 1]"]
```

)

Comment: I am seeing the same thing in Wordpress with 4.6

Answer (score 1):

It was a redirect issue.  Not all domains were redirecting to the domain that civi had listed as its base domain.  example.com needed to redirect to www.example.com for instance.